# Filtering in SQL between evening previous day and morning current day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to filter a table between 4 pm of previous day and 4am of current day but am at loss of how to query that.

Something like:

```
WHERE
dateColumn >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AND dateColumn <= GETDATE()
AND DATEPART(hh, dateColumn) >= 16 AND DATEPART(hh, dateColum) <= 4
```

I realize the second line in WHERE statement is obviously incorrect and will not return any results but that is to give an idea of what I am trying to do. All help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the type of your date column? `dateadd(hour, 16, cast(cast(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) as date) as datetime2))`

Comment: You can try something like this `SELECT CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, DATEADD(d,-1,CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))) + '16:00'` and without dateadd.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways you could do this, this gets the datetime at 1600 yesterday and 1600 today.

```
WHERE dataColumn >= dateadd(hour, -8, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate()))) 
AND   dateColumn <= dateadd(hour, 16, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())));
```